# Erro no db:create no Mac OSX Montain Lion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
alexandesigner$ rails server

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Users/alexandesigner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.15/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Users/alexandesigner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.15/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Como resolvê-lo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema!

seguindo um post no SOEN, nesta pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773633/symbol-non-found-when-run-rails

It means that you're trying to run ruby 1.8.7 with gems that were compiled for ruby 1.9.3 - something has got its knickers in a twist

I'd try re-installing the gems into a clean gemset and make sure you are using the ruby version that you think you are

Que rapidamente traduzido:

"Isso significa que você está tentando executar ruby 1.8.7 com gemas que foram compilados para ruby ​​1.9.3 Eu ia tentar re-instalar as gemas em uma gemset limpo e verifique se você está usando a versão ruby que você pensa que é"

Eu percebi que era as versões do mysql2 que estava utilizando, só alterei e setei no gemfile de 0.3.15 para 0.3.11

Comment: Que bom! Você pode aceitar sua resposta. Aí no lado esquerdo, abaixo dos votos.